# Which Flask extension should I choose to work with API's?

Tags: flask, microservices, flask-restless

I've tried to work with Flask-Restless, but I'm not sure, I think its unable to work with factory pattern and blueprints.

I want to find something similar to Restless(simple generation/JSON format) but compatible with the factory pattern & blueprints so, Which FP&BP supported extension you recommend me to build an API under those requirements?

Answer (score 0):

You can build a REST API using Blueprints quite simply without relying on any Flask extensions.

This is a non-working example, but should help you get started. Set up a basic blueprint file (let's assume it's called `user.py`):

```
import json
from flask import Blueprint, jsonify, request
   
bp = Blueprint('user', __name__, url_prefix='/user')

@bp.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def user_details():
    if request.method=='GET':
         # Access elements in the JSON passed in to the call using request.json
         # Return a JSON result by passing a dictionary to jsonify
         return jsonify({'result': 'ok', 'var1': 'val1'})

    if request.method == 'POST':
         # Access elements in the JSON passed in to the call using request.json
         # Return a JSON result by passing a dictionary to jsonify
        return jsonify({'result': 'ok')
```

and then just add the blue print to your Flask server as normal, e.g. your `__init__.py` will have something like this:

```
from flask import Flask
import user
app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(user.bp)
```

Comment: thank you for answering, but I actually need some extension to abstract models from the database and build in a easy way the resources holding the format json api 1.0 or similar .I actually found an extension called Flask_Restjsonapi but its dense, so I'm still looking for an extension similar to Flask_restless wich implements an interface(the methods get, post , put, patch etc) to abstract and interact with data models through API restful.